# Properties of the Riemann integral - is my proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I've attempted to tackle the following problem and I'm not sure about my solution:

> $f:\:\left[-1,1\right]\:\rightarrow \:\mathbb{R}$ is an odd and
> integrable function. Show that:  $$\int
>  _{-1}^1\:\:f\left(x\right)dx=0$$

This can be done by showing $\int _0^1\:\:f\left(x\right)dx=-\int _{-1}^0f\left(x\right)dx\:$.
My approach was thus:

If $P$ is a partition of $\left[0,1\right]$ containing $n+1$ elements, then $-P=\left\{-p\::\:p\in P\right\}$ is evidently a partition of $\left[-1,0\right]$ with the same number of elements and symmetrical intervals. Likewise, for the set $T$ which contains an arbitrary point for each "subinterval" of $P$, the set $-T=\left\{-t\::\:t\in T\right\}$ contains a symmetrical arbitrary point for each subinterval of $-P$.

Therefore:
$$\int _0^1f\left(x\right)dx=\lim _{λ\left(P\right)\to 0}\left(R\left(f,P,T\right)\right)\:\:=\:\lim \:_{λ\left(P\right)\to \:0}\left(\sum _{i=1}^n\left(Δx_i\cdot f\left(t_i\right)\right)\right)\:
=_{oddity\:of\:the\:function}\:\lim \:\:_{λ\left(P\right)\to \:\:0}\left(\sum \:_{i=1}^n\left(Δx_i\cdot \:-f\left(-t_i\right)\right)\right)\:
=\:-\lim \:\:_{λ\left(P\right)\to \:\:0}\left(\sum \:_{i=1}^n\left(Δx_i\cdot \:f\left(-t_i\right)\right)\right)=-\lim \:_{λ\left(-P\right)\to \:0}\left(R\left(f,-P,-T\right)\right)=-\int _{-1}^0f\left(x\right)dx\:\:$$

Is that a sufficient proof? I'm afraid it's an abuse of notation and I'm not allowed to manipulate the limit of the Riemann sum so cavalierly.

Comment: Why go into the definition? $\int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 -f(-x) \mathrm{d}x = -\int_{-1}^0 f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ just by elementary properties of the integral!

Comment: If it has already been proven in your course that $\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c$, and the method of substitution has also been proven, then Ben Steffan is correct. If only $\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c$ has so far been proven, then you are correct, but should stop trying to cut corners and write it out carefully in detail. Only once you are fully satisfied yourself that it can indeed be done is it acceptable to cut a corner. If $\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c$ has not yet been proven, then your proof does not work.